# Refer to Root of Web Site in JScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-2.0

To refer to the root of a website in  asp I use an ASP control (normal hyperlinks don't work!) and use the tide ~

However I am trying to achive the same with Jscript and it does not work.

I have set up a folder structure to better organise the files on my website. I have placed a Jscript file within the root of the folder structure and refer to it like this

"/superslight.js" this is in the master page

The user navigates to a page that is one folder down the link breaks down becuase it's not looking at the root of the site but the root of the current folder

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/superslight.js")%>"></script>

Answer (score 0):

use  two dots to refer to the parent folder :
assuming that you have the following folders structure

root---->pages---->myFile.aspx
root---->scripts---->myScript.js

you refer to myScript.js in myFile.aspx like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/myScript.js" />
```